# How to create a NoData raster mask in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, nodata

I need to create a mask of `NoData` pixels from an elevation raster dataset. ArcGIS directly recognizes the `NoData` values as such, so I don't see an option to address them e.g. in the Raster Calculator to create a simple raster Mask where `1` stands for the data gaps in my original elevation raster.

Could anyone help me with a default method or at least a flexible workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that there is a tool called "[Is Null](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/is-null.htm)" for this exact purpose. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use an environmental parameter as

arcpy.env.nodata = 'MINIMUM' or any other parameter.

[Under ArcGIS 10.3](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/nodata.htm)

[Under ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/nodata.htm)  < Not tested

To setup Environmental parameters for nodata

[ArcMap 10.3](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/setting-geoprocessing-environment.htm) > Under Raster Storage